# Show Folders that are created in the previous month C#

Tags: c#

I have a directory that shows all the subfolders within the folder. I need to only display the folders that have been created within the previous month. So it could be (-1) month or (-30) days. How can I do this?

```
    static void getSubDirectoryList3(string workingDirectory)
    {
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"F:\Apps\SoftwareAndApplications\").Filter;

        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(directory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what problem and or issue are you currently having when running this code? please edit your question and give some valid examples of what the output is vs what your current expectations are when executing the code you have posted.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is very simple... Did you try something?

```
static void getSubDirectoryList3(string workingDirectory)
        {
            string[] directories = 
            Directory.GetDirectories(@"F:\Apps\SoftwareAndApplications\").Filter;

            foreach (string directory in directories)
            {
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                if(dir.CreationTime.Month == DateTime.Now.Month - 1)
                    Console.WriteLine(directory);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Or better yet, replace the `Directory.GetDirectories("...")` call with `new DirectoryInfo("...").GetDirectories()` so you get a list of DirectoryInfo objects from the beginning.

Comment: yes I tried adding OrderBy.CreationTime but I don't think its the correct one I'm looking for. However, the code above doesn't display the folders created from the previous month.

Comment: @Crazytraveller oh what? I think it's correct. The code gets only the folder with the creation date being the last month, by a filter DateTime.Now.Month - 1

Comment: yeah, but it only displays a folder from 12/2015

Comment: you want to list all folder **from** the last month or **within** the last month?

Comment: **From** the last month

Comment: Replace  ``if(dir.CreationTime.Month == DateTime.Now.Month - 1)`` by ``if(dir.CreationTime.Month >= DateTime.Now.Month - 1)``

Comment: nope, still doesn't work it displays everything but the previous months folders...

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq:

```
string[] directories = 
 Directory.GetDirectories(@"F:\Apps\SoftwareAndApplications\")
 .Where(dir=> Directory.GetCreationTime(dir).Month == DateTime.Now.Month - 1)
 .ToArray();
```

Comment: Faster than other solution! +1